# Android acting as a wifi server?

Tags: android, wifi, wireless, lan

I am working on a few devices that need to send raw data to an android device wirelessly (wifi). The android devices needs to be able to support multiple devices so I figured a server is best. Is there a way to have the android device act as kind of a router/server access node by producing its own LAN network?

Any pointers appreciated,
~Aedon

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.2 supports running as an accesspoint, which sounds like what you're after.

I believe this was possible in earlier versions if you had gained root access.

Comment: Thank you that. To receive the data just set up a socket to listen to the port? Is it that simple?

Comment: Probably you want to do it using multicast sockets, but yes it is that simple.

Comment: !re there any tutorials on interfacing with it yet?

Comment: Official doc is: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html be sure to have the permission for your app too. I can't find a great tutorial on it, but several games use it so it clearly does work.

Comment: Kk thanks again. How would the server work, extend ServerSocketChannel?

Comment: Nmv it would seem that I would just use Datastream channel and it would act kind of as a server.